# dtexec.exe /SET won't recognize the Property Path

Tags: ssis, ssis-2008, dtexec

I have a SSIS package set up for a data export that we regularly do, which I have no problem running in Visual Studio, but which is giving problems when I try to use the command line to execute it while using /SET to change variables (If I use the default values, not changing any variables, it also works fine.).

I have bool variables indicating whether specific parts of the package should run, and date variables to filter out specific dates. I need to be able to change them on execution of the package using dtexec.exe

I'm running something similar to this:

```
PS C:\Users\ssrsreports> dtexec /f "C:\Users\ssrsreports\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\ALCOSAN Export Dev\ALCOSAN Export Dev\bin\Deployment\Package.dtsx" /SET \package.variables[user::doRectype1].value;"true" /SET \package.variables[user::endDate].Value;"2016-01-01"
```

And I'm getting an error saying:

```
Argument ""\package.variables[user::doRectype1].value"" for option "set" is not valid.
```

I have tried a number of permutations of the property path, with and without quotes, various capitalizations, and an alternate constructions which replaces ".Value" with "Properties[Value]".

Does anyone have insight into what is going on here and how to fix it?

EDIT: I tried to create a dummy integration with just one variable and a script that prints it to a message box. My integration works without /SET but fails If I try to use it. Is there a setting I am not aware of that could be causing this?

Comment: How about this: `/SET "\Package.Variables[endDate].Properties[Value]";2016-01-01`

Comment: This construction is failing for me as well. Same error.

Comment: They are all package-level variables... does that make a difference?

Comment: @GeoLawton - Was there any resolution for this issue?